# How to set MAC address and other keys when building aosp?

Tags: android-source, android-7.1-nougat, serial-number

In the process of building aosp, we do some steps and after all we have a .img or otapackage to burn on device.

But I want to set mac addresses and **serial numbers** when building? I am working on AMLogic platform and I want **SPECIALLY** to burn my keys on EFUSE part of chip so later no one can change them!